# Problems with Structs

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

Hey I just started on structs in C++ a few days ago and I have few errors in my code. I've tried working them out with my teacher but all he gives me are cryptic answers that don't help at all. Any help you guys give me would be very appreciated.

Here are the errors:

```
G:\Program01.cpp||In function 'void getData(StudentType*)':|
G:\Program01.cpp|99|error: 'name' was not declared in this scope|
G:\Program01.cpp||In function 'void convert(std::string&)':|
G:\Program01.cpp|163|error: expected ';' before ')' token|
G:\Program01.cpp||In function 'void assignGrades(StudentType*)':|
G:\Program01.cpp|192|error: request for member 'average' in 'students', which is of  pointer type 'StudentType*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)|
G:\Program01.cpp|192|error: request for member 'grade' in 'students', which is of pointer type 'StudentType*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)|
G:\Program01.cpp|193|error: request for member 'average' in 'students', which is of pointer type 'StudentType*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)|
G:\Program01.cpp|193|error: request for member 'grade' in 'students', which is of pointer type 'StudentType*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)|
G:\Program01.cpp|194|error: request for member 'average' in 'students', which is of pointer type 'StudentType*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)|
G:\Program01.cpp|194|error: request for member 'grade' in 'students', which is of pointer type 'StudentType*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)|
G:\Program01.cpp|195|error: request for member 'average' in 'students', which is of pointer type 'StudentType*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)|
G:\Program01.cpp|195|error: request for member 'grade' in 'students', which is of pointer type 'StudentType*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)|
G:\Program01.cpp|196|error: request for member 'grade' in 'students', which is of pointer type 'StudentType*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)|
G:\Program01.cpp||In function 'void printGradeSheet(StudentType*)':|
G:\Program01.cpp|221|error: expected primary-expression before ')' token|
G:\Program01.cpp|222|error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << std::setfill<const char*>(((const char*)" "))'|
G:\Program01.cpp|234|error: expected primary-expression before 'students'|
G:\Program01.cpp|235|error: expected primary-expression before ']' token|
G:\Program01.cpp|255|error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token|
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

// constant declarations:
const int NUM_STUDENTS = 20;
const int NUM_SCORES = 5;

// struct/class declarations:
struct StudentType {
  string name;
  int scores[NUM_SCORES];
  float average;
  char grade;
  };

// function prototypes:
void getData (StudentType students[]);
void assignGrades (StudentType students[]);
void printGradeSheet (StudentType students[]);
void getFile (ifstream& fin);
void convert (string& name);
void printTopStudents (StudentType students[], float highscore);
float findHighAverage (StudentType students[]);


int main() {
StudentType students [NUM_STUDENTS];

getData (students);
assignGrades (students);
printGradeSheet (students);


return 0;
}

void getData (StudentType students[]) {
ifstream fin;
getFile (fin);
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STUDENTS; ++i) {
    int total = 0;
    getline (fin, students[i].name);
    students[i].name = convert (name);
        for (int j= 0; j < NUM_SCORES; ++j) {
            fin >> students[i].scores[j];
            total += students[i].scores[j];
        }
        students[i].average = static_cast<float>(total) / NUM_SCORES;
        fin.ignore (INT_MAX, '\n');
}

void getFile (ifstream& fin) {
string filename;
cout<< "Enter filename: ";
cin >> filename;
fin.open (filename.c_str());
  while (!fin) {
  cout << "Could not open" << filename << ", try again." << endl;
  cout << "Enter filename: ";
  cin >> filename;
  fin.open (filename.c_str());
  }
}

void convert (string& name) {
string::size_type n;
string b;
string s;
n = name.find (".");
  if (n!=string::npos) {
  // found middle initial
  s = name.substr(n+2, name.size()) + ", " + name.substr(0, n+1));
  name = s;
  }
  else {
  // no middle initial
  n = name.find(" ");
  b = name.substr(n + 1, name.size()) + ", " + name.substr(0, n);
  name = b;
  }
}

void assignGrades (StudentType students[]) {
  if (students.average >= 90) students.grade = 'A';
  else if (students.average >= 80) students.grade = 'B';
  else if (students.average >= 70) students.grade = 'C';
  else if (students.average >= 60) students.grade = 'D';
  else students.grade = 'F';
}

void printGradeSheet (StudentType students[]) {
  float highscore;

  cout << setw(25) << left << "Names" << setw(10) << right << "Grades";
  cout << setw(2) << right << "Avg." << setw(2) << right << "Grade" << endl;
  cout << setfill(-) << setw(40) << '-';
  cout << setfill(" ");
  for (int k = 0; k < NUM_STUDENTS; ++k) {
    cout << left << setw(25) << students[k].name;
    cout << "        ";
      for (int g = 1; g < NUM_SCORES; ++g) {
          cout << right <<  students[k].scores[g] << " ";

      }
      cout << showpoint << setprecision(2) << fixed;
      cout << students[k].average << " " << students[k].grade;
      cout << endl;
   }
highscore = findHighAverage (StudentType students[]);
printTopStudents (students[], highscore);
}

float findHighAverage (StudentType students[]); {
  float highscore;
  float score;

  highscore = students[0].average;
  for (s = 1; s < NUM_STUDENTS; ++s) {
    score = students[s].average;
    if (highscore < score)
        highscore = score;
  }
return highscore;
}

void printTopStudents (StudentTypes students[], float highscore); {
cout << "Student with the highest grade: " << endl;
cout << "---------------------------------" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STUDENTS; ++i) {
  if (students[i].average == highscore)
    cout << students[i].name << setw(5) << right << highscore << endl;
  }
    cout << "---------------------------------" << endl;
}
```

Thank You for any help you can provide

Comment: Can you please post the *relevant* code?

Comment: Did you try actually reading the error messages? Do you understand them at all?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Reading error messages? How novel.

Comment: thanks guys for the help. I am just starting with structs, but I have had some experience in C++. I've never encountered most of these errors, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `assignGrades` function you lack of an array index when accesing students:

```
 // students is an array not a single struct
 if (students.average >= 90) students.grade = 'A';
 else if (students.average >= 80) students.grade = 'B';
 else if (students.average >= 70) students.grade = 'C';
 else if (students.average >= 60) students.grade = 'D';
 else students.grade = 'F';
```

If you want to assign the grades for all students in the array you have to use a for:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < NUM_STUDENTS; ++i)
 {
    if (students[i].average >= 90) students[i].grade = 'A';
    else if (students[i].average >= 80) students[i].grade = 'B';
    else if (students[i].average >= 70) students[i].grade = 'C';
    else if (students[i].average >= 60) students[i].grade = 'D';
    else students[i].grade = 'F';
 }
```

Also in function `getData`:

```
students[i].name = convert (name);
```

"name" is part of struct StudentType so you should write:

```
students[i].name = convert (students[i].name);
```